# Clickable icon in Vaadin Grid executes code multiple times after each call of setItems()

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

In my Vaadin app, I'm showing a `Grid` with items of a custom class `Transaction`. This grid shall behave like this:

1. It shall contain an "Actions" column which, in turn, shall contain one or more icons. For simplicity, let's consider only one icon.
2. Each of these icons shall be clickable.
3. With a click on an icon, some code shall be executed with the `Transaction` item of the current row. Here, a simple `Notification.show()`.

I managed to implement this with the following code:

```java
private final Grid<Transaction> transactionGrid = new Grid<>(Transaction.class, false);
transactionGrid.setItems(transactionService.getItems());

transactionGrid.addColumn(getActionsRenderer()).setHeader("Actions").setAutoWidth(true);

private ComponentRenderer<Icon, Transaction> getActionsRenderer() {
    final Icon replyIcon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.ENVELOPE);
    return new ComponentRenderer<>(transaction -> {
        replyIcon.addClickListener(event -> Notification.show(transaction.getOrderNumber()));
        return replyIcon;
    });
}
```

Clicking on the icon shows a notification with the transacion's `orderNumber`. The problem is the following:

The application also provides a "reload" button which does nothing more like this:

```java
refreshIcon.addClickListener(event -> {
    final List<Transaction> transactions = transactionService.getItems();
    transactionGrid.setItems(transactions);
});
```

After having clicked the refresh icon, a click on the row's `replyIcon` shows three notifications for the same data. After the next refresh it shows five, then seven, etc.

So it looks as if each refresh adds two whatever "components" which all register the identical click listener. When debugging, I can see that there are multiple `ClickEvent` on the `eventBus` but I ha ve no idea where they come from.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My mistake was to define the icon outside the `new ComponentRenderer<>` statement. Having changed the code to this seems to do the trick:

```java
private ComponentRenderer<Icon, Transaction> getActionsRenderer() {
    return new ComponentRenderer<>(transaction -> {
        final Icon replyIcon = new Icon(VaadinIcon.ENVELOPE);
        replyIcon.addClickListener(event -> Notification.show(transaction.getOrderNumber()));
        return replyIcon;
    });
}
```